# How to load a 20GB json file to read in pandas?

Tags: json, pandas, lazy-loading, large-files

I have a JSON file that is 19.4 GB in size. I tried a lot of methods to read the file. For example: `pandas.read_json(filename)` simply crashes the notebook. I am looking for ways to load the file in a lazy way. Like, 1GB at a time and then dump it in a SQLite or a neo4j db to analyze the data. Any ideas for this will be really appreciated.

Comment: if you have it on linux, you could use @Ferris' suggestion below, or use `jq`, since you are moving data into a db.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html) as it would be distributed and lazy also, PySpark APIs could be used to analyze the data in memory and if required dataframe could be dumped to a database.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.local.dir', '/remote/data/match/spark')
conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '2100')
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '10g')
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.driver.memory', '10g')
sc = SparkContext(appName='mm_exp', conf=conf)
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

data = sqlContext.read.json(file.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

split by row, if the JSON file's data is separated row by row.

```sh
# In bash, split by 1,000,000 lines per file
split -d -l 1000000 file_name.json file_part_
```

then handle each file.

---

or use chunksize:

```py
df_iter = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize = 100000, sep='\n', header=None)
for df in df_iter:
    # handle the dataframe
    break
```